# Dynamically link 'Sheet2' notes as companies change in 'MasterSheet'

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I'm having a problem with setting up a sheet to move notes with the corresponding company name.

Let me explain:
"MasterSheet" has column A and B, column A for Account Names, and column B for website URLs.

Sheet2 should pull column A and B data from MasterSheet. This has already been done with: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MasterSheet!A:A<>"", {MasterSheet!A:A, MasterSheet!B:B}, "")

However, there's an issue. When I add, move, or remove a company on MasterSheet, Sheet2 will update on column A and B (which is what the formula is pulling), but the issue is that there are notes tied to those companies on Sheet2, those notes aren't moving when there's an update to the MasterSheet, so the notes would then be next to the wrong company.

I understand that the formula is "static" and will only match what is on "MasterSheet", and that the notes aren't tied to that specific company. I've heard that this is possible to do with scripts, but I don't have a background in programming, so any help or resources would would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to note that companies will constantly be shifted around, and multiple sheets are added, so it would be most ideal to have this automated instead of manually shifting things around.

Here's an editable spreadsheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OP1Orf7F8veslrwTpDvQbNlGL9mpbNwMpXeTvGOw2eY/edit?usp=sharing)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OP1Orf7F8veslrwTpDvQbNlGL9mpbNwMpXeTvGOw2eY/edit?usp=sharing)

I've had some help and this is the script that was given, but doesn't work:

```
function setOtherNotes() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = sh.getSheetByName("MasterSheet");
  const destSheet = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  const sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange("A:C").getValues();
  const destData = destSheet.getRange("A:C").getValues();

  // Clear existing notes in destination sheet
  destSheet.getRange("C:C").clearNote();
  
  // Loop through each row in the destination data
  for (let j = 0; j < destData.length; j++) {
    let destAccountName = destData[j][0];
    let destWebsiteURL = destData[j][1];
    
    // Loop through each row in the source data
    for (let i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
      let sourceAccountName = sourceData[i][0];
      let sourceWebsiteURL = sourceData[i][1];
      let note = sourceData[i][2];
      
      // Check if the Account Name and Website URL match
      if (destAccountName === sourceAccountName && destWebsiteURL === sourceWebsiteURL) {
        // Set note in destination sheet
        destSheet.getRange(j + 1, 3).setNote(note);
        break; // Exit the loop once the note is set
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your notes in column C are not linked to the values in columns A & B in any way.  So when the `ARRAYFORMULA` is executed if changes only A & B.  What you need is an `onChange` trigger to check if rows are added or deleted.  Try this.

```
function onChange(e) {
  try {
    let spread = e.source;
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
    let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
    if( cell.getSheet().getName() === "MasterSheet" ) {
      if( cell.getRow() > 1 ) {
        let a1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
        a1.setValue("");  // Remove the formula before adding/removing a row
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        if( e.changeType === "INSERT_ROW") {
          sheet.insertRowBefore(cell.getRow());
        }
        else if( e.changeType === "REMOVE_ROW" ) {
          sheet.deleteRow(cell.getRow());
        }
        a1.setFormula('=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MasterSheet!A:A<>"", {MasterSheet!A:A, MasterSheet!B:B}, ""))' );
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

You install this trigger from the script editor.

[image]

[image]

References

- [Trigger event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Sheet.getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell())